# Prove that $ \int \limits_a^b f(x) dx$ = $ \int \limits_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Hi everyone I have been trying to prove that that $ \int \limits_a^b f(x) dx$  = $ \int \limits_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$ .  Heres my attempt:

LS: $ \int \limits_a^b f(x) dx$  = $ \int \limits f(b) - \int \limits f(a) $

RS: $ \int \limits_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$ = $ \int \limits f(a+b-b) - \int \limits f(a+b-a) $ = $ \int \limits f(a) - \int \limits f(b) $

as you can see I have really not been able to make the 2 sides equal each other. Any help on this i appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Change of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $y=a+b-x$. Then $dy/dx=-1$ and thus $∫_a^bf(a+b-x)dx= ∫_b^a-f(y)dy = ∫_a^bf(x)dx$

Comment: Those are some unusual unicode characters you have there. How did they come into your possession?

Comment: i wrote first on word and then made copy-paste

Comment: I took the liberty of unburdening you from them.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Make the change of variables $ y=a+b-x $.